# Can I remove a merge/changeset from the past?

Tags: git

Say I am using git by creating a new branch for each feature, then merging into master.

So each merge is very narrow in that it is for a specific feature.

After 10 commits like this, can I go back and remove the 5th merge somehow?

Say it was a feature I didn't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this constantly. Here is how: http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

You want to reset master to just before the 5th merge. Now merge in the rest.

One suggestion would be to use a release candidate branch instead of master. Use master to mark what was released.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
git rebase -p --onto bad-merge^ bad-merge master
```

This rebases everything *after* the undesired merge onto the commit before it, with the `-p` preserving merges.

(Normally you'd remove a past commit using `git rebase -i`, but unfortunately does not work well with `-p`; you can't remove a merge commit. This is noted under BUGS in the manpage.)

Comment: You can't easily change your mind again and merge this feature in after some edits.

Comment: Eh? I've just removed that single merge commit. You can easily redo that merge later if you want. This seems a lot better than having to redo everything that came after it.

Comment: If you use revert, the merge still exists in history and won't get applied